# Wordpress and SEO: how to mask a path/pull content from another domain

Tags: wordpress, seo, apache-config

I have a marketing site (running WP) at http://www.example.com, and our application (our own software) at https://secure.example.com.  We let people subscribe at https://secure.example.com/subscribes?some=tokens-here

We have thousands of backlinks out there now pointing to secure.example.com because of this, but apparently it doesn't help our ranking since it points to the "secure" subdomain, and not the marketing "example.com" or "www.example.com".

Is there some way to mask a path on the WP marketing site to pull content from the application instead?  E.g. "www.example.com/subscribes" would be a mask for "secure.example.com/subscribes"?

I know that a `<Location>` block in the httpd.conf could do it, but I don't think we have access to that with it being a hosted/managed WP instance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to have two pages "www.example.com/subscribes" and secure.example.com/subscribes for the users to register here and add a canonical link to the other page.

from secure.example.com/subscribes, a canonical link pointing to

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/subscribes" />
```

This will make the page rank flow from secure. example to www.example.com

Now after this if the users searched for your subscribe page, the new page will appear to Google "www.example.com/subscribe"

The canonical link tells Google to ignore the current page and follow the canonical one.